# Android Studio doesn't run the program but shows a cell phone sandbox

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've been trying to learn and write some Java apps using Android Studio on my Windows 7 64-bit. Everything goes well but as I try to run the app using the Android Studio, nothing runs just a screen of an Anroid phone. I've taken a pic below to explain more the problem.

[image: android cell phone image]

Comment: did you get any error after click "Run"?

Comment: @WenChao No, there is nothing.

Comment: Anything in your logcat?

Comment: There are somethings when I run the studio itself : 

Path.approximate() not fully supported

(2 similar errors not shown.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are running emulator from AVD manager !

1.Click Run 'app' from Run menu 
 or `Shift` + `F10` or click on run icon

2.Choose your AVD

Comment: That's it! I was running the AVD instead of app. Thank you so much!. I also appreciate for the time and efforts made by other dear friends to help me.